# Proof by mathematical induction inequality

Tags: proof-writing, induction

i'm trying to work on this problem but i'm stuck and can't seem to continue.

For $n=1,2,3\ldots$
$$a_1=1, a_n=\sqrt{2+a_{n-1}}\;,\qquad n > 1$$
I then have to prove that
$$a_n < 2\qquad\text{for } n=1,2,3,\ldots$$
I first do my base case:

$$a_2=\sqrt{2+1}=\sqrt{3} $$
which is less than $2$.

I then put my goal to work towards as $$a_{k+1}<2$$
Then induction goes as follows
$$a_{k+1}=\sqrt{2+a_k}$$
This is where i get stuck and i'm unsure how to continue

Can i just use the fact that since $n > 1$, then
$$\sqrt{2+a_2}=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}$$ which is less than two?

Comment: Hey, in your last couple of statements, did you mean $n\gt1$?

Comment: Hi yes, in my last statement i ment n>1

Comment: Also, can't i use the fact that $a_{k+1}=\sqrt{2+a_k}$ thus $a_{k+1}=a_k$?

Comment: Use $a_k < 2 \implies \sqrt{2+a_k} < \sqrt{2+2}=2$.

Comment: Not exactly; for your inductive step, your assumption is $a_n\lt 2$, which you wish to use to prove that $\sqrt{2+a_n}\lt 2$. Note that it doesn't follow that $a_{n+1}=a_n$.

Comment: @MathLover Where does the squareroot 2 appear from on the right hand side of the inequality?

Comment: @StanK. I used the fact $a_k < 2$ implies $2+a_k < 2+2=4$. Consequently, $a_{k+1}=\sqrt{2+a_k} < \sqrt{4}=2$.

Comment: @MathLover Thanks, can't i also use the fact that $a_{n-1} < 2$, thereby $ a_k =\sqrt{a_{n-1}+2}<\sqrt{(n-1)+2} = \sqrt{n+1}<2$ ??

Answer (score 0):

After your base case, you have your inductive hypothesis.

Assume $ a_k < 2, \ \forall k \geq 1$

From there you want to show that if its true for k, it will be true for k + 1.

Now let $n = k + 1$, so $a_{k+1} = \sqrt{2 + a_k}$,  which we know becuase thats the formula we are given.

Well, we know what $a_k$ is, because thats our inductive hypothesis. so we know $2+a_k < 4$ since $a_k < 2$. The square root of a number less than 4, is less then 2. So we $a_{k+1} < 2$

So we showed that its true for a base case, and that if its true for any number we pick, it will be true for the next number. So then by induction we showed that $a_n < 2, \ \forall n \geq 1$